# Return column name with values

Tags: vb.net

This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE `opcije_mp` (
`idopcije_mp` int(11) NOT NULL,
`naziv` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`opc` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`Prodaja` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`Kalkulacije` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`Zaduznice` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`Predisponacije` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`Robno` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`KUF` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`KIF` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`Narudzbenice` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`Nalozi` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`Akcijske_cijene` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`Servisna_roba` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`Ostalo1` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`Ostalo2` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`Ostalo3` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`idopcije_mp`)
```

Data sample:

```
INSERT INTO `opcije_mp` VALUES (1,'MP default','1','1','1','1','1','2','3','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1');
```

My goal is to use column names to identify my buttons which i have in Tilebar and use value under column to run some code (hide, show, repaint, disable) buttons

```
  <dxnav:TileBar  x:FieldModifier="public"  x:Name="maloprodaja" Margin="10,0,0,10" ItemSpacing="5" FlyoutShowDirection="Default" ItemColorMode="Standard" AllowItemSelection="true" Orientation="vertical" HorizontalAlignment="LEFT" Padding="20,0,20,20">
                <dxnav:TileBarItem  Name="Prodaja" Content="Prodaja" Background="#FF901B45" TileGlyph="{dx:DXImage Image=BOSale_32x32.png}" Width="150"/>
                <dxnav:TileBarItem  Name="Kalkulacije" Content="Kalkulacije" Background="#FF901B45" TileGlyph="{dx:DXImage Image=BOTask_32x32.png}" Width="150"/>

            </dxnav:TileBar>
```

My current function returns only values under columns

```
Public Function vratiTipke()
    Dim result = New List(Of ReturnList)
    Try
        ManageConnection(False, konekcija) 'Open connection
        Dim strQuery As String = "SELECT * FROM info.opcije_mp where idopcije_mp = 1;"
        Dim SqlCmd As New MySqlCommand(strQuery, dbCon)
        Dim reader As MySqlDataReader = SqlCmd.ExecuteReader()
        While reader.Read()
            Dim TempResult As New ReturnList
            TempResult.tipka1 = reader(0)
            TempResult.tipka2 = reader(1)
            result.Add(TempResult)
        End While
        reader.Close()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " & ex.ToString())
    Finally
        ManageConnection(True, konekcija) 'Close connection
    End Try
    Return result
End Function


  Public Class ReturnList
    Public Property tipka1 As String
    Public Property tipka2 As String
End Class
```

My button names will be same as column names in my table (excluding first two columns which are used to identify "preset")

Comment: You haven't explicitly asked a question, but if you did then I expect the answer would be something to do with using the `GetName` method as shown in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connectors/en/connector-net-ref-mysqlclient-mysqldatareader.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can identify the columns by their actual names.

```
Set db = CurrentDb()
Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset("opcije_mp")
Dim fld As DAO.Field
For Each fld In rs1.Fields
    'Make an array or something, these should be LTR order
Next
Set fld = Nothing
```

You can use the loop to set your button names as well, for example.